# Renting a Manual Car in the US

Tags: usa, car-rentals

Neither specific websites of Hertz, Budget, Alamo, Enterprise, Thirftly or FOX allow you to specify that you want to rent a manual car. Neither do Kayak, Hotwire and Priceline.

Is there a way to book a manual car in the US?

Comment: try relayrides.com for peer to peer options if you really really want to drive a stick.

Comment: I used ability to drive a manual transmission car as a mating filter. My adult sons would never get partnered if they did the same. (One of them doesn't drive at all.)

Comment: Why would you ? Driving a car with an automatic transmission is very easy, even if you are used to drive a manual.

Comment: Can you explain why you want  to rent a manual car? Personal preference? Learning to drive stick? Want to rent a real sports car? Also where in the US do you want to rent it?

Comment: TL;DR - The answer is no. Only a small percentage of the American population knows how to drive a manual transmission.

Comment: I'm surprised at the commenters questioning why the OP wants a manual car.  Personally, I can't understand why anyone would drive an automatic car, especially a so-called 'sports car'.

Comment: @CraigWelch i see reasons for *owning* car with manual transmission. But *renting*? You use a car for, say, a week then forget about it.

Comment: Indeed @el.pescado, often driving some thousands of miles. In Europe, we always ask for, and get, a manual diesel car.

Comment: I would suggest that you turn this problem into an opportunity; see it as an opportunity to learn to drive automatic (which as others have said, isn't hard). You might like it. I could go off on a tangent about why they are better, but this isn't a car forum... :)

Comment: How long do you plan to rent the car for? If it's a few days, then you may need to call around for an independent, small-town rental company that may have one -- sometimes the big ones may still have a clunker on the lot, but that could be a rarity. If it's several months, perhaps purchasing one makes sense... if you can get insurance. Decisions, decisions..

Comment: @CraigWelch: Two reasons.  1) Performance.  The days of a skilled stick-shift driver being able to outperform a modern automatic transmission are long past.  2) Safety.  The more you can get a machine to do for you, the less concentration you have to spend on doing it yourself, which is always important when you're operating a piece of heavy machinery at speeds high enough that one mistake can mean death for yourself or those around you.  Between the one and the other, there's really no valid reason to drive a stick anymore.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: **Regarding performance:** Unless you are on a drag strip, the _feeling_ of performance in a stick is better than the feeling of performance with an automatice. The OP presumably is not running moonshine, but would rather _enjoy_ the feeling of actually driving (not just steering) the vehicle. **Regarding safety:** the safer machine is the machine whose controls one is familiar with. Perhaps an automatic-bred driver in an automatic is safer than a manual-bred driver in a manual, but less safe than either is a manual-bred driver in an automatic.

Comment: Please remember that the comments should not be used to discuss whether manual or automatic shifting is better. You can do that in the chat. I'll delete all further comments in this direction.

Comment: The OP might already have a car and want to rent another one specifically to try/learn to drive with a stick, say before a trip to Europe. No need to debate the pros and cons, the question is clear.

Comment: @CraigWelch not surprising, as in Europe manual transmission is pretty much the norm (though automatics are gaining ground, especially with the increasing popularity of hybrids) so rental companies tend to have a large supply of them. In the US and Canada that's not the case.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: *"skilled stick-shift driver being able to outperform a modern automatic transmission are long past"* — not they aren't unless by "modern automatic", you mean sequential double-clutch transmission, which is used in high-end European cars, rather than cars on US market.

Comment: @MasonWheeler **Safety** With a _manual_ car you are always focused and concentrated on driving. When driving automatic - you forget about driving do it without thinking, automatically, which isn't always safer. Apart from getting drowsy quicker, it's also harder to get the right torque when you need it in intersections and other situations using automatic, rather than manual. **Performance** I haven't seen a rental with a double-clutch automatic transmission in US, so it's still wrong :) **Why?** Because of better feel of the car, more control, and when well controlled - a better gas mileage.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter No it isn't, especially when you also have to contend with driving on the opposite side of the road to what you usually do, and consider local traffic signage, road systems and laws on top.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

tl;dr: **You cannot**

Generally US rental companies don't have option to select transmission type, because they don't offer anything other than automatic.

The only cars in popular rental companies would have any chance to have manual transmission, would be high-end sports cars. And even so, that chance is slim to none. For example at Hertz you have *"adrenaline collection"* with cars like *Mustang GT Premium* or *Corvette Stingray* and they still *only* have automatic transmission option. They even have European sports cars like *BMW M5* or *Porsche Cayman*, also *only* automatic.

The only way to get rental with manual, would be to use one of the peer-to-peer rentals and choose category "exotic cars" or similar. But even with these I haven't seen much offer of manual transmission (practically none at all).

Comment: I've absolutely seen manuals on RelayRides in the past though most were pickup trucks. It looks like they're getting away from allowing manuals though https://support.relayrides.com/hc/en-us/articles/203992950-Is-my-car-eligible-

Comment: A large number of people in America don't know how to drive stick.  Rent a manual and you're likely to have the clutch beat up.

Answer (score 18):

Some companies rent manual cars. Here's one such company in [San Diego](http://renty.biz/manual-transmission-stick-shift-rental/).

I can't help but chuckle that they have a paragraph explaining the context, and have 'how to drive a proper car' (my wording) sessions.

I've not lived that long in the US, and finding a manual car to purchase was a struggle. We got a very fine two year old Saab, but gave up on the idea of getting a diesel powered vehicle.

Comment: Do the car shops even know how to fix trouble with a manual-transmission car? This could get quite expensive... :D

Comment: I can't speak to the US, but in Canada neither buying nor repairing manual transmission cars has been difficult. (However not all dealership employees can drive them, sometimes they have to get someone else to bring the car around to the front.) However buying a used one might be a different story.

Comment: Another hazard @kateGregory is valet parking. The other night one valet didn't have anyone on staff who would drive my car. At least they were honest. I'd hate to have them somehow drive off then have an accident selecting reverse in the garage.

Comment: If only a manual is a "proper car," then I do hope you manually crank the engine to start it rather than take the wimpy way out by using a battery.

Answer (score 6):

In North America the percentage of drivers who can use a clutch and manual transmission without burning one of them out inside a week is rather small. Driving schools teach with automatic transmissions, not all that many drivers bother to learn about anything other than D and R.

The rental car companies now have a simple choice: buy cars everyone can use, or buy cars a lot of renters will either decline or damage. You also won't get diesel rental cars for the same reason - the engine will be ruined the first week because someone put regular gas in it.

I've rented in Europe (Germany) and got manual-transmission diesels every time. Also every time the rental agent heard my Canadian accent and asked me if I can drive a manual. I said I own one back home, which ended the discussion.