# Auto/Manual transmissions in Europe

Tags: driving, spain, eu, automobiles

I've noticed that Spanish people prefer manual transmissions, and automatics are harder to find there (opposite to USA).

Is that the case in the rest of EU, or just a Spanish thing?

Comment: I guess this has chagned a bit over the past decades. Manual has always been standard in Europe. Don't have figures, so I only comment. It's believed manual shifting allows for faster acceleration.

Comment: I think it’s more of a rest-of-world than rest-of-EU thing. There’s only a handful or so if countries where automatic is preponderant, though I couldn’t find detailed figures though. But I can tell you France is mostly manual.

Comment: I can only add that 20 years ago in Italy an automatic was a special request for rental cars.

Comment: At one time in UK, apart from luxury cars the automatic was generally for people who did not like driving, and so the cars that had them were often of low powered spec. Nearly everybody had a manual. But the modern auto box is very different and much more popular, efficient, and will out-perform a human driver (at least on the up-shifts).

Comment: [Why is it harder / more expensive to rent cars with automatic transmission in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64318/13777), https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-majority-of-cars-in-Europe-have-manual-transmissions, https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/3ul8yp/why_is_manual_transmission_more_common_in_europe/

Comment: As an American, I was _thrilled_ to be getting a rental in Austria with a manual! All 4 in my family are more than capable of driving a stick. When we got there, I was most disappointed to find that the agency had "upgraded" us to something with an autotragic transmission (I thought that the guy figured a bunch of Americans _couldn't_ drive a manual though I told him I daily-drive one). TBF, the car was actually a bit bigger and had a built in GPS that helped us quite a bit, but I was still very disappointed. TL;DR: No, it's not just a Spanish thing.

Comment: I actually taught a US Friend to drive stick shift since they were travelling to Iceland and manual rental cars were substantially cheaper.

Comment: When I grew up in Germany, 'automatic' was considered to use more gas and suck power from the engine, and was associated with 'grandpa with hat', meaning old, slow, and helpless people. As a consequence, we wouldn't want to be caught dead in an automatic car. Nowadays, the technical reasons are no longer true. Still, there are more stick shift cars, and  automatic rentals are typically more expensive.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As a European, I would say that we definitely tend to drive manual cars way more than automatic, although automatic cars are becoming more common especially in city settings.

Compared to, let's say 10 years ago, rentals now offer more automatic cars, but still way less compared to manual cars, so they run out fast.

This is true, in my experience, in Italy and other Southern European countries and in parts of Ireland and the UK.

Comment: Also, electric cars almost never have gears, so the number of cars with a stick shift will probably go down in the next 20-30 years. In fact for Italy I believe for *personal* cars the number of automatic shift cars is probably so small that electric cars are already at around the same number of a couple of percent points. Rentals are probably way more likely to offer automatic cars.

Comment: My hybrid _probably_ has no gears, but it does have a selector for "drive" vs. "low."  I haven't had it long enough to look into the technical details.

Comment: @mirabilos Not only North American tourists. I have relatives in the UK who drive manuals at home but prefer automatics when going to mainland Europe because of the trouble of having to adjust to driving on the opposite side.

Comment: @mirabilos I learned on a manual, and always loved it.  But I've owned mostly automatic vehicles for at least 15 years because (1) manuals are much harder to find and (2) it is extremely tiring when trying to commute with a manual transmission giving the starts and stops that happen.

Comment: @psubsee2003 well it’s the other way round in Europe, almost all used cars are manual, and people tend to not learn automatic. I’ve been completely taken by surprise by its nōnlinear behaviour and loss of control when I _had_ to drive one because the rental couldn’t provide a manual one.

Comment: Automatic cars are mainly a physical/mental disability thing over here (the Netherlands). No one willingly chooses to get their drivers' license in an automatic, as that means you get a limited license that will never allow you to drive a manual like a normal person, and you will always end up having to pay extra when you want to buy or lease another car as automatics are more expensive than regular cars. That's why they're pretty uncommon, they're either a necessity because of some kind of disability to drive a normal car, or a rich person's luxury.

Comment: @mirabilos You don't have to "learn" automatics.  Anyone who can drive a manual can also drive an automatic with little or no adjustment.  The reverse is of course not true.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that's not true at all.  You have to learn that the car starts moving before you finish talking your foot of the break, among other things.  For my wife that was extremely stressful the first time she drove an automatic.

Comment: Me at a European rental car agency.  *comes back into the shop* "how do I drive this? There's no clutch pedal!"  "But-but- you're an American! We thought..."

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the first five minutes of any automatic drive for me is a comedy of errors as I keep instinctively going for the clutch and hitting brake instead. They’re two separate skill sets and need to be individually learnt.

Comment: @RobinWhittleton I have big feet.  The clutch-brake confusion is unfortunate indeed, especially as I typically do it when first driving out of the rental lot, so not very fast, and the car lurches to a stop as I try to put the brake pedal on the floor.  But I think the more detrimental mistake for me is the habit of throwing the shifter forward into park while the car is moving.

Answer (score 27):

> Is that the case in the rest of EU, or just a Spanish thing?

[Percentage of cars with automatic transmission among 2018 sales](https://www.eupedia.com/europe/vehicle_maps_of_europe.shtml#Automatic) (sales, not current fleet, and EVs are regarded as having automatic transmission):

[image]

> This map was made using data from the [ICCT European vehicle market statistics: Pocketbook 2019-2020](https://theicct.org/sites/default/files/publications/European_vehicle_market_statistics_20192020_20191216.pdf).

---

Country-specific stats:

[France](https://blog.direct-assurance.fr/actu/ventes-voitures-neuves-france-boite-automatique-majoritaire#:%7E:text=Tout%20s%27est%20acc%C3%A9l%C3%A9r%C3%A9%20ces,%C3%A9quip%C3%A9es%20d%27une%20bo%C3%AEte%20automatique.) via [Gtranslate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=Bo%C3%AEte%20automatique%20%3A%20seulement%208%25%20des%20ventes%20en%E2%80%A6%202004%0AAcheter%20une%20voiture%20avec%20une%20bo%C3%AEte%20automatique%20%3F%20%C3%87a%20n%E2%80%99allait%20pas%20encore%20de%20soi%20dans%20les%20ann%C3%A9es%202000.%20Comme%20l%27indique%20le%20site%20Caradisiac%2C%20en%202004%20seulement%208%25%20des%20voitures%20neuves%20%C3%A9taient%20dot%C3%A9es%20d%E2%80%99une%20bo%C3%AEte%20auto.%20Ces%20v%C3%A9hicules%20trainaient%20avec%20eux%20l%E2%80%99image%20d%E2%80%99une%20%C2%AB%20voiture%20de%20papy%20%C2%BB%20rappelle%20le%20journal%20Sud-Ouest.%20Confortables%20certes%2C%20mais%20pas%20peu%20performantes%E2%80%A6%0A%0ATout%20s%E2%80%99est%20acc%C3%A9l%C3%A9r%C3%A9%20ces%20derni%C3%A8res%20ann%C3%A9es.%20En%202016%2C%20les%20voitures%20avec%20bo%C3%AEte%20automatique%20atteignent%2025%25%20des%20ventes%20de%20voitures%20neuves.%20En%202021%2C%20elles%20franchissement%20un%20nouveau%20pallier%2C%20hautement%20symbolique%20%3A%20d%E2%80%99apr%C3%A8s%20RTL%2C%20plus%20de%20la%20moiti%C3%A9%20(54%25)%20des%20voitures%20neuves%20vendues%20en%20France%20sont%20%C3%A9quip%C3%A9es%20d%27une%20bo%C3%AEte%20automatique.%20Ces%20derni%C3%A8res%20ont%20pris%20le%20dessus%20sur%20les%20boites%20manuelles.%20Il%20s%27agit%20d%27une%20premi%C3%A8re%20historique%20sur%20le%20march%C3%A9%20de%20l%27auto%20fran%C3%A7ais.%0A%0AVers%20la%20fin%20des%20voitures%20avec%20bo%C3%AEte%20manuelle%20%3F%20&op=translate):

> **Automatic gearbox: only 8% of sales in… 2004**
> Buying a car with an automatic transmission? It was not yet self-evident in the 2000s. As the Caradisiac site indicates, in 2004 only 8% of new cars were fitted with an automatic gearbox. These vehicles dragged with them the image of a "grandpa's car" recalls the Sud-Ouest newspaper. Comfortable certainly, but not inefficient...
>
> Everything has accelerated in recent years. **In 2016, cars with automatic transmission reached 25% of new car sales**. **In 2021**, they will reach a new, highly symbolic level: according to RTL, **more than half (54%) of new cars sold in France are equipped with an automatic gearbox**. The latter have taken over the manual gearboxes. This is a historic first on the French car market.

[UK](https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news/new-cars/analysis-are-manual-gearboxes-way-out):

[image]

Compared to the [US](https://www.quora.com/Are-cars-with-manual-transmissions-dying-out):

[image]

FYI: [Why Manual Transmissions Are Dying … and What’ll End Them for Good](https://www.cars.com/articles/why-manual-transmissions-are-dying-and-whatll-end-them-for-good-424059/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136938/discussion-on-answer-by-franck-dernoncourt-auto-manual-transmissions-in-europe).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine thanks I edited the post

Answer (score 5):

Same in the whole Eastern Europe from Greece and Turkey all the way to Estonia and Finland.

The prevalence of manuals is even more pronounced in ex-socialist countries where the cars are on average much older and the drivers' habits and expectation are shaped accordingly.

Almost everyone here can drive manual and this is taken for granted (if one can drive a car at all, which is NOT taken for granted as it is in the US).

Automatic rentals are offered, but you have to double-check if you want an automatic. These are usually bigger, more expensive and have worse fuel economy.

The last point is also somewhat important since the gas prices are not like in the US either.

Comment: "worse fuel economy" in a _modern_ automatic is not true unless the driver is _very_ skilled in using a standard economically.

Comment: No matter what automakers say, even the most recent automatics are 10-20% worse compared to the average driver. But the other, more important factor is that the AVAILABLE automatic rental cars are bigger and this imposes worse fuel mileage, all other things being equal.

Comment: @WGroleau it doesn't take masses of skill, but plenty of drivers choose not to think about driving efficiently.  That's doubly a shame as the forward-planning involved is good for safety as well

Comment: @fraxinus that’s a common meme in Europe but unfortunately it’s not true. Automatic gearboxes have been better than the average human for at least a decade.

Comment: @JonathanReez but cars with automatic transmission are, on average, placed higher on the consumption scale, by means of what models are available with what options. So choosing a manual transmission one will still, on average, save.

Comment: @mirabilos I guess so but that’s not how the argument is presented in the “manual is more fuel efficient” meme

Comment: @mirabilos What you're saying here is heavier cars use more fuel.

Answer (score 1):

Many people think an automatic gearbox is detrimental to the pleasure of driving in Europe. This attitude is (slowly) changing now with the introduction of faster sequential automatic gearboxes with the option of manually controlling the gears.

Answer (score 0):

High gasoline prices in Europe, compared to the United States, made the small improvement in mileage worth staying with more efficient manual transmissions. Recent automatic transmissions have a much smaller penalty (if any!), so a barrier to acceptance has disappeared.

It has now become routine in the USA to see a story of a car thief who abandons the stolen vehicle because he couldn't drive a stick shift. Google turned up three YouTube videos on the first try. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU2CHu4WBI8).